# Unable to add Google Test NuGet package to a Visual Studio Linux C++ project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017, nuget, googletest

I have a Linux C++ project in Visual Studio 2017 which contains unit tests, and I'm trying to add the Google test framework to it. I have added the gtest NuGEt package to the project, and in every file that uses this, I have a `#include "gtest/gtest.h"`. This works fine in a Windows-based unit test project, but in the Linux C++ project (all else being equal as far as I can tell), the NuGet package doesn't seem to be able to work, and when I compile I get the following error :

> gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because VS Linux projects are compiled and executed on a connected Linux machine (see Tools / Options / Connection Manager). Which in your case does not have Gtest installed.

Comment: Ok. So it doesn't link the binary from NuGet for gtest? Does NuGet not work with Linux C++ projects? Or will it work after I install Gtest on my Linux machine?

Comment: @AlexKven, Can't say anything about NuGet - as far as I know it's a .NET thing. But I am pretty sure it doesn't install anything on a remote computer. Neither do Visual Studio installer - the user has to install g++ and gdb manually before starting Linux development. If it does not install even the required tools, why do you expect it to install an optional third-party component? I suppose you have to install it yourself, and make sure that g++ can locate its .h and libraries.